# SPFieldUserValue on a Person or Group field where multiple selection is turned on

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a list Called Notification Groups which has a Person or Group field where multiple selection is allowed. Following is my code

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Notifications Group"];
                        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                        {
                            string fieldValue = item["Specific users"].ToString();
                            SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, fieldValue);
                            string name = userValue.LookupValue;

                        }
```

But when i print the string name only the first user of each item gets printed without #id; rest all users of a particular item get printed with #id; any way of using `SPFieldUserValue` with Person or Group with multiple users selected? Anyone any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Notifications Group"];
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
    string fieldValue = item["Specific users"].ToString();
    SPFieldUserValueCollection users = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, fieldValue);

    foreach (SPFieldUserValue userValue in users)
    {
        SPUser user = userValue.User;
        //Do something with user
            int userId = user.ID;
            string userName = user.LoginName;
    }
}
```